# toJson and fromJson cross platform support

Tags: android, json, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have an android application written in Kotlin. I have a number of classes, and for each class I make use of `Gson's` `toJson` and `fromJson` functions for those classes. For example:

```
class A{

fun toJson():String {
        return Gson().toJson(this)
    }

fun fromJson(jsonString:String):A{
            return Gson().fromJson(jsonString, A::class)
   }
}
```

I have another class `B`:

```
class B{
    
    fun toJson():String {
            return Gson().toJson(this)
        }
    
    fun fromJson(jsonString:String):B{
                return Gson().fromJson(jsonString, B::class)
       }
    }
```

The way I used this was creating an instance of the class and then calling the method (note: I am creating an instance of this class (`class A`) in another class:

```
val a = A()    
a.toJson()
```

But I am now trying to convert this into a kotlin multiplatform project but unsure how to go about approaching the `to` and `from` json conversions in kotlin multiplatform.

I tried creating expect functions as such:

```
expect fun toJsonClassA():String
expect fun fromJsonClassA(jsonString: String): A

class A{

}
```

and then implementing them the actual implementations as such:

```
actual fun toJsonClassA(): String {
    return Gson().toJson(A::class.java)
}
```

With the above platform specific implementations, I cannot call the `toJsonClassA` or the `fromJsonClassA` functions with the instance of the class name.

This won't work:

```
val a = A()
a.toJsonClassA()
```

Any help or advice as to how I can implement the Json serialization and de-serialization in Kotlin Multiplatform will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `Gson` is JVM only so you'll need to use something else elsewhere. If you're after JS you can try to use https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization

Comment: @al3c I see, at the moment, I am only after android and iOS. Do you have any libraries in mind that could assist me?

Comment: Kotlinx.serialization works on iOS as well since it can be compiled into native.

Comment: @GiorgosNeokleous Thank you, I shall give that a try.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your question. You need a multiplatform json serializer (not GSon coz it for jvm only) and at the moment I know only `kotlinx.serialization`. And with it, your code should look like this

```kotlin
@Serializable
class A {
  fun toJson() = Json.stringify(A.serializer(),this)
  companion object {
    fun fromJson(json: String) = Json.parse(A.serializer(),json)
  }
}
```

While that will work, You don't need the `toJson` and `fromJson` methods. Since when you have a class like

```kotlin
@Serializable
class B {}

val b = B()
```

all you need with `kotlinx.serialization`

- To convert to `Json`, `Json.stringify(B.serializer(),b)`
- To parse `Json` to kotlin object, `Json.parse(B.serializer(),"{}")`

Comment: this was very helpful. Thank you for your time and effort, I really appreciate it.